# Difficulty in understanding the following problem from Gallian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group of order $p^n$ , where $p$ is a prime and $G$ has exactly one subgroup of each divisor of $p^n$. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

The hint is given at the back but I am not able to understand it. So could you please explain it to me?

Hint:Let $x \in G$ have maximum order , say $ | x|=p^t $. Now let $y\in G$. Then $|y|=p^s \leq p^t$. Since $<x>$  has subgroup of order $p^s$ , we have $<y>   \subseteq  <x>$.

How does this prove that $G$ is cyclic?

Comment: Well, if a cyclic subgroup contains every element of the group...That hint is more like a solution.

Answer (score 4):

The hint implies every other element $y \in G$ also lies in $<x>$. So $G \subset <x>$ and as $x \in G$, $<x> \subset G$.

Thus $G=<x>$ is cyclic.